# How to update a Drupal 6 website to latest release with drush?

Tags: 6, drush, updating

I want to update my Drupal 6 website (version 6.36) to the latest realease (6.38).

When i'm using the shell-command "drush update drupal", i'm getting following result:

```
Drupal                     6.35      6.35      Installed version not supported
```

How can i do an update to the latest release with drush?

Comment: **[Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As near as I can tell, drupal.org just removed all of the release xml for all contrib modules, and every version of Drupal 6.x core except for the latest release.

See [the Drupal 6.x release xml](https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/6.x) for reference; all versions except 6.38 have been removed. Ah, look, [the Views 6.x release xml](https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/6.x) contains content again!  Just a short while ago, it was gone.

Without the full release XML for Drupal 6 core, Drush cannot your existing versions; if it has no information about the current release, it gives up.  It is possible that this situation was accidental, and is being updated (c.f. the views release XML, which was recently restored).  Maybe this will start working again later.

Comment: Here is the issue on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2675892

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't, but I think Drush will be updated to handle this situation. I suggest that you follow [the relevant issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/2024) on GitHub. (There is already an ugly work-around for older versions of Drush.)